# Handing login information to the customer

Tags: password-management, corporate-policy

We have a software system with several different users (let's say 10) and a single super user. A super user is a regular user with the privileges needed for managing other user accounts.

This is a production control software system for large manufacturing companies, so nothing cheap. We would like to solve the risk of misuse of the super user account. Let's say the super user account belongs to some manager and that the customer company decides to part with him, and not on good terms. In that case, the customer company needs some means to disable the super user account to avoid its misuse.

We have a recovery account for that, hierarchically above the super user - let's call it the master user. The master user should be accessible to management of the customer company and should be used only for disabling the super user and creating a new one.

Question: Instructions how to access the super user are included in the contract with the customer. How should we provide the master user instructions if we do not want to have them in the same document? The contracts are signed electronically over distance.

Comment: The customer should be able to set their passwords. You should never give them access (credentials) to an account, because you should never be _able_ to give them access (or if the software in limited, they should immediately change the password while being told how by the installer. If there is a contractual way to enforce this, the installer should not leave the premises while capable of taking control of that account.)

Comment: Of course. I am not suggesting that we would set the master user's password and write it down somewhere, god forbid. I'm mainly trying to figure out a reasonably safe way to hand the master user username to the customer.

Comment: Usernames aren't secrets.  Don't broadcast them, or otherwise make it easy for an attacker to get a list of them, but they don't have to be treated with the same care as passwords.  Still, you can have the customer set that username as well, when the software is being installed.